# Sql query from two tables: Consumed time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. In the table **UnRevisedTable** goes the raw data and in the table **RevisedTable** there is only entries of revised values which a human inserts when he finds a value in **UnRevisedTable** than he doesnt likes.

In **UnRevisedTable** there is one entry every minute and in **RevisedTable** there is one entry for every unwanted entry in  **UnRevisedTable**.

The purpose of those two queries is the same: Show me the union of revised and unrevised data replacing the unrevised data when there is revised data.

I started writing the query2 but it was too slow. Then i wrote the query1 and the query1 is much, much faster.

My question is why query1 is faster than query2? Thx.

```
query1:
    SELECT o.start_date_time,
        CASE WHEN r.start_date_time IS NULL THEN o.value ELSE r.value END AS value,
        FROM UnRevisedTable o LEFT JOIN RevisedTable r ON o.start_date_time = r.start_date_time
        WHERE o.start_date_time >= '".$start."' AND o.start_date_time < '".$finish."' ORDER BY start_date_time ASC;

query2:
    select * from(
      select RevisedTable.* from RevisedTable where start_date_time between '".$start."' and '".$finish."' 
          union 
      select UnRevisedTable.* from UnRevisedTable where start_date_time between '".$start."' and '".$finish."'
    ) as t1 group by start_date_time;
```

As [Abhik Chakraborty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039843/abhik-chakraborty) sugested here are the explain query1 and explain query2:

query1:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                    | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | o     | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL                   |    9 | Using where |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | r     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | Mydb.o.start_date_time |    1 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------------------------+------+-------------+
```

query2:

```
+----+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+    
| id | select_type  | table      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                           |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <derived2> | ALL   | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL |   14 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED      | RevisedTable  | range | PRIMARY    | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |    2 | Using where                     |
|  3 | UNION        | UnRevisedTable| range | PRIMARY    | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL |   10 | Using where                     |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union2,3> | ALL   | NULL        | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | NULL |                                 |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: use `explain first query` and then `explain 2nd query` and share the result in the question.

Answer (score 2):

First, the two queries do not do the same thing.

- The first query returns only times from `UnrevisedTable`.  If there are times in the `RevisedTable` not in `Unrevised`, you won't get them.
- The first query is using a `join`.  And, if you have an index on the join key, `start_date_time`, then the index will be used.  Aggregation is less likely to use indexes.
- The first query will not remove duplicates that might exist within each table.  The second does.
- The two queries will not necessarily return the same `value` when there is a match in the two tables.

The second query is doing two aggregations, but no joins.  The first aggregation is for removing duplicate values (for the `union`) and the second for the outer `group by`.

I would start by revising the second query to be:

```
select start_date_time, max(value) as value
from ((select start_date_time, value
       from RevisedTable
       where start_date_time between '".$start."' and '".$finish."' 
      ) union all
      (select start_date_time, value
       from UnRevisedTable
       where start_date_time between '".$start."' and '".$finish."'
      )
     ) t1
 group by start_date_time
```

You will probably also find that this is slower than the `join`.  The MySQL engine does a better job of implementing joins than aggregations.

Comment: Hi there. First of all thanks for the answer. 
Im ploting the data so i fastly discovered the two qiereis arent exactly the same, your explanation surely helped me to understand them better. 
The amount of data in those two tables is large(10 years with one entry every 1 min). As i said im ploting this data and ploting so much data is imposible. Im using this two queries as subquery of a query which groups my data by time intervals.
Having such a complex query and such amount of data make all the process slow. Im going to dicuss the adventages and drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

To answer you question the slower query uses a `UNION`, which removes rows which are duplicated between the first and second tables.  This will require a sort which is often expensive.  You can see that in query 2's plan as a filesort.  You can eliminate this sort by using a `UNION ALL` instead.

You may like to consider replacing the CASE statement in query 1 with [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) which returns the first non-null.  It will make for an easier-read query and may run faster.

```
SELECT 
    o.start_date_time,
    COALESCE (o.value, r.value) AS value
FROM UnRevisedTable o LEFT JOIN RevisedTable r ON o.start_date_time = r.start_date_time
WHERE o.start_date_time >= '".$start."' 
AND o.start_date_time < '".$finish."' 
ORDER BY start_date_time ASC;
```

Comment: Thx for the answer.
Im going to give a try to the UNION ALL.
The COALESCE is not going to be usefull because the revion of the data sometime involves setting value to null.